# Running Tomcat inside a Docker container - Container Exited at startup

Tags: docker, tomcat7, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am learning Docker and trying to build a Dockerfile that will run a Tomcat using a docker-compose rather than docker.

The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
# Base the image on tomcat
FROM tomcat:7.0.82-jre7

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat

# Install updates & commands
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim

# Add some pre-set files
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf

# Run the Tomcat on port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

# Start tomcat
# CMD ["bin/startup.sh", "run"]
```

The docker-compose.yml file is as follows:

```
 version: '3'

services:
tomcat:
    image: tomcat:7.0
    build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 8888:8080
    container_name: tomcat7
    volumes:
        - ./tomcat7:/usr/local/tomcat:rw
    entrypoint: /bin/bash /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
    tty: true
```

The tomcat7 docker container starts but in exit mode.

Any idea how to make it run?

Comment: any output from docker logs?

Comment: Where can I find the docker logs?

Comment: try `docker service logs tomcat` . If that fails , then look into `/var/log` and search for the docker demon logs

Comment: also, your compose file specifies an image and a build context..... are you trying to use an existing image or build a custom one?

Comment: Build a new image